# getLocalAddress returns 127.0.0.1 on connected socket

Tags: java, sockets, tcp, ip

I am writing a client Java program that needs to know the local IP Address used to connect (via tcp) to the remote server.

The problem is that the call Socket.getLocalAddress().getHostAddress() returns wrongly (ONLY IN FEW CASES) 127.0.0.1, while in the majority of the cases/PCs it works fine...

Here is the snippet of the code used:

```
public static String getLocalIPAddress(String serverIP, int port) throws UnknownHostException
{
    System.out.println("Executing getLocalIPAddress on "+serverIP + ":" + port);
    InetAddress inetAddress = InetAddress.getLocalHost();
    String ipAddress = inetAddress.getHostAddress();
    try {
     Socket s = new Socket(serverIP, port);
     ipAddress = s.getLocalAddress().getHostAddress();
     System.out.println("Local IP : "+s.getLocalAddress().getHostAddress());
     s.close();
    } catch (Exception ex) {}
return ipAddress;
}
```

The output I obtain in succeeding case is

```
Executing getLocalIPAddress...
Executing getLocalIPAddress on 1.2.3.4:80
Local IP : 6.7.8.9
```

The output I obtain in failing case is

```
Executing getLocalIPAddress...
Executing getLocalIPAddress on 1.2.3.4:80
Local IP : 127.0.0.1
```

Note that in the failing case it has not gone through the exception.

Any advice is very appreciated.

Comment: Do you mean Local IP :... should be followed by the same thing as if you went to [link](http://www.whatismyip.com)?

Comment: Is the remote address remote? or is it 127.0.0.1? I suggest you print out the remote address along with the local address. If they are both 127.0.0.1 there is no problem here to solve.

Comment: yes local address is 6.7.8.9 while remote address is 1.2.3.4

Answer (score 0):

`Socket.getLocalAddress()` returns the local address to which the socket is bound. So "127.0.0.1" suggests that the socket is bounded to the loopback interface. Similarly, "6.7.8.9" means that the socket is bounded to another interface of the client which has the address of "6.7.8.9".

One way to specify the local address and port on the client side used for binding is to use [the following constructor](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/net/Socket.html#Socket%28java.net.InetAddress,%20int,%20java.net.InetAddress,%20int%29)

```
    Socket(InetAddress address, int port, InetAddress localAddr, int localPort)
```

In the example you provided, you can use

```
    Socket s = new Socket(serverIP, port, InetAddress.getLocalHost(), 0);
```

to specify the local host IP address (rather than loopback address) for client socket binding. I have tested the above example and it works.

Comment: There's no point in specifying the local bind-address unless you have some weird routing that you have to do manually, e.g. a VPN. The fact that this socket is bound to 127.0.0.1 isn't actually a problem in the first place.

Comment: I agree, but it seems the question poster is concerned about using the loopback address for binding. It would be nice if more information could be provided for the actual scenario.

Comment: It doesn't seem like that at all. He isn't attempting to specify a local bind-address. He is just concerned for some reason about the bind-address he is getting by default.

Comment: The problem I'm trying to solve is to get the local ip address used to connect to the remote server. I'm not looking for specifying any specific Ip address whatever the system decides to use is fine for me but I want to know what is that address, and sometime it returns 127.0.0.1